# CQ run mode when any other name is given?

Tags: aem

I wonder what will happen if I will give the sling.run.mode='abc,def', then CQ will start in which run mode. I tried, and it started in Author, i didnt get why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default run mode between publish and author if none is specified is author. It makes a bit more sense if you ask yourself the question as the package configs ask the question, "am I currently running with a publish run mode"? No? Then I'm running as an author!

The classic head scratcher here is when your DevOps guys are wondering why their publish**er** server isn't running as a publish server, and instead as an author.